# Basic authentification does not work if tracd running from script

Tags: debian, basic-authentication, trac

I am trying to setup trac 0.12.5 on debian 7. Trac is running as standalone service, tracd.
I've generated .htpasswd file for basic authentification according with wiki instructions.

When I run tracd from console, evetything is ok, I can log into tracker:

```
$ sudo tracd -s -p 8000 --basic-auth="Trac,/var/Trac/.htpasswd," /var/Trac/
```

But when i run it via init script and try to log in, it says:

> Trac Error Authentication information not available. Please refer to
>   the installation documentation.

piece of init script which I suspect of error:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="--daemonize -s --pidfile=$PIDFILE --port=$PORT --basic-auth=\"Trac,/var/Trac/.htpasswd,\" $PROJECT_ENV"
```

full script: http://pastebin.com/kdDDjzvf

So how can i make tracd start automaitcally?

Sorry, if it's duplicate question, but i can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after I've removed quote and equals sign in daemon options:

DAEMON_OPTS="--daemonize -s --pidfile=$PIDFILE --port=$PORT --basic-auth**=\"** Trac,/var/Trac/.htpasswd,**\"** $PROJECT_ENV"

became:

DAEMON_OPTS="--daemonize -s --pidfile=$PIDFILE --port=$PORT --basic-auth Trac,/var/Trac/.htpasswd, $PROJECT_ENV"

Comment: That helped me find a solution to my problem. Exactly the same behavior (in my case) is when alias is set in .bashrc for example and all possible values for arguments are hardcoded. I spent quite a while trying to figure this out. Thanks man!